# How do I use Firebase Realtime Database in my android app to track the location of a person?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, firebase, geolocation

I am making an app in which I would be able to view the location of another person having the same app and it would show his movements in realtime.I will be using Firebase Realtime Database for it,but I don't know how to get started.So,the app would send its location to the firebase database and another user using the same app would be able to trace this user and get his location in google maps. Please provide with any links for this or show the steps to get started.

Comment: Have you seen [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java)?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to first implement the locations api through Google play services to get the user's location. Please note that the rest of how this is done depends on how you have structured your Firebase. The location may just be the lat lon variables in the user object, so you may just be updating the child values in your user object. Without knowing your structure, I can only give a general idea of how to do this. Let's say you have a location object associated with a user somehow. You can then setup a location class of sorts that has the relevant variables for the location; something like:

```
public class MyLocation {
    public double lat;
    public double lon;
    public String nameOfPlace;

    public MyLocation(double lat, double lon, String name){
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        nameofPlace = name;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the users location whenever you like, for this you could use a [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html), [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), [GCMTaskService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService), etc. Then assuming you have already set up Firebase, create a new object and send it up:

```
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(latFromApi, lonFromApi, name);
```

How your firebase is structured determines whether you push the object or use `setValue`, etc. But you should either be updating the location in the user's class, or if you have a flat structure and have a location that a user has a reference to, just update the location and if you are pushing the location for the first time, make sure the user's reference to the location is updated as well.

After that you can set up a [ChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) or, more likely, a [ValueEventLister](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) to listen for changes to a location.